# isomorphic quotient rings?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ring-isomorphism

I have trouble in determining, whether two rings are isomorphic:

Let's have $R = GF(3)$ and rings $R[x]/(x^2+x+2)$ and $R[x]/(x^2+2x+2)$.

How can one determine whether these two rings are isomorphic? I know that both of them will consist of polynomials with degree 1. And if they are isomorphic, what is the isomorphism?

Appreciate any ideas. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since both $\;x^2+x+2\;,\;\;x^2+2x+2\in\Bbb F_3[x]\;,\;\;\Bbb F_3=GF(3)\;$ are irreducible quadratics, both

ideals $\;I_1:=\langle x^2+x+2\rangle\;,\;\;I_2:=\langle x^2+2x+2\rangle\le\Bbb F_3[x]\;$ are maximal, and thus both quotient

rings $\;\Bbb F_3[x]/I_1\;,\;\;\Bbb F_3[x]/I_2\;$are fields of order $\;3^2=9\;$ ...

Comment: So is it correct to say, that if two finite fields have same number of elements, they are isomorphic, and thus the given rings are isomorphic as well?

Comment: Yes @ab, that's what my answer is based on: there's only *one* field of any given finite cardinality (a power of a prime, of course) up to isomorphism.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\ $ Over GF($3$): $\,f(x) = x^2+x+2\,\Rightarrow\,f(x\!-\!1) = x^2+2x+2.$